# MySQL JDBC syntax error exception

Tags: mysql, exception, syntax

I had this MySQL project that I worked on a couple months ago, and just recently I got back into developing with it. However, when it executes certain statements, it gives an error. The SQL statement is `DELETE FROM table WHERE expires < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAYS)`

Now, This used to work. I also know that the java code behind it is working, because there are no other exceptions. Also, I plugged that statement into a SQL client and it gave a similar error.

The error in the java console is this: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAYS)' at line 1`
and then a stack trace which leads me to the line of code that calls `executeUpdate()` on a prepared statement.

I don't remember updating or changing much since I developed before and it was working fine.

EDIT: My java code is like this:
`add(37, "DELETE FROM table WHERE expires < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAYS)");` the function add() is calling connection.prepareStatement() on the given string and putting it into an array of PreparedStatements. The line that is throwing the exception is `statements[37].executeUpdate();`

Comment: `INTERVAL '?' DAYS` wrap the days in single quotes see if it work that way or `INTERVAL '? DAYS'` I don't recall which one is the right

Comment: He should not need quotes there, AFAIK.  Can you show us the Java code you used to make the JDBC call.  Relevant portions should suffice.

Comment: "Used to work" - doesn't now.  What else changed?  Believe the Java console - assume your code is wrong and dig into why.  You'll make progress faster if you forget the phrase "was working fine".  Start with MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `S` from `DAYS`, referring to [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

`DELETE FROM table WHERE expires < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY)`

```
select date_add(now(), interval 1 day); //Works
select date_add(now(), interval 1 days); //Doesn't work
```

Comment: My flippin gosh... It worked! my syntax error is gone! I always miss these kinds of things...

Comment: @Pocketkid2, happy coding!